# how to get only day number from date in flutter

Tags: flutter, date, split

I am trying to get day from date, and date comes from the api response, api response look like this

```
 "data": [
{
    _id: 6116c2e12760f71630342604,
    username: 'abc',
    Date: '2021-08-13',
   
  },
  {
    _id: 6119ba9162069c32ccdf11c3,
    username: 'acv',
    Date: '2021-08-15',
    
  }
]
```

i am trying to do it like this

```
date=Response.data['data']['Date']);  //if i get date here 2021-08-15 
day=date.split('-') //then will split it [2021,08,05]
day=date[2] //and then will get the day 05
```

but it is not working, it sends this error

`type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'`

when i print this line `day=Response.data['data']['Date']);` it send same error, it is not getting date, but when i  print `onResponse.data` it prints the api response.

please help how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date String is in standard ISO format, simply use `DateTime.parse` then you can get the day easily, it would also allow you to check that the date is valid (`parse` will fail if date is not valid, see [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.24.2/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html)):

```dart
String dateStr = Response.data['data']['Date']);
DateTime dateObj = DateTime.parse(dateStr);
print(dateObj.day);
```

If this is a custom format, you could use `DateFormat` from `intl` package ([documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html)):

```dart
String dateStr = Response.data['data']['Date']);
DateTime dateObj = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').parse(dateStr);
print(dateObj.day);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try or you will use `day[2]`

```
day=Response.data['data']['Date']);  //if i get date here 2021-08-15 
day=date?.split('-').last; //then will split [05]
print(day) //and then will get the day 05
```

Comment: but i am not getting the date at first, how i can split then?

Comment: you should try out with null check

Answer (score 1):

you should use `date.split("-").last` and actually your index is wrong it should be `day=date[2]`

Comment: but i am not getting the date at first, how i can split then?